# Android ActionBar Overlap with Settings Options

Tags: android, android-actionbar

As you can see from the image below my Action Bar Menu Items overlap my custom ActionBar. This is because I use the theme .NoActionBar and then in .java declare my own action bar as follows:

```
public class MenuActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_activity);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp">
```

and the layout...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"
    ></include>

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

So as you can see the problem arises from having a .NoActionBar theme. I have tried looking around and adding a padding to the top of my Menu items however it doesn't work. Any help appreciated.

[image: problem image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally expected behaviour and follows the [Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#) official guidelines.

> Menus appear above all other in-app UI elements.

It is brought to you by either a `Theme.Material` theme (if you are on API > 21) or an `Theme.AppCompat` if you are using `support-v7` as it looks. You shouldn't worry about that.

If this is not what you are expecting from your app, try switching to older themes, like `Holo` stuff. From a design point of view this is not really recommended.

Comment: Cheers sorry guess I'm just updating myself aha